# el comando de linux funciona bien en la terminal, pero no al estar en secuencia de comando en varias lineas

Tags: linux, script, terminal

un programa básico de buscar archivos por su extensión y moverlas a una nueva ubicación, por ejemplo:

busca archivos por extensión "mkv" y muevelos a la carpeta/x

```
user@user$ find /home/example1 -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec [mv -f example/directory] \;
```

pero cuando inserto mas de una linea dentro del mismo script, el sistema dice que no entiende la funcion "-exec"

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

para hacer correr el script he usado un

```
sh programa
```

ejemplo de secuencia de comandos en script :

```
find /carpeta1/carpeta -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec [mv -f /carpeta35] \; 
find /carpeta3/carpeta -type f -name '*.avi' -exec [mv -f /cartepa22] \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que le pasas al exec es lo que está entre {} y lo que te está fallando al ponerlo en una única linea es que hace falta un punto y coma mas entre el final del primer find y el principio del siguiente.

```
 -exec loquesea {} \; ; find /carpeta3/carpeta 

find /carpeta1/carpeta -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec mv {} -f /carpeta35 \; ;    find /carpeta3/carpeta -type f -name '*.avi' -exec mv {} -f /cartepa22 \;
```

Comment: ok, la nueva linea de comando ha quedado asi:

user@user:~$ find /home/carpeta -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec {mv -f /media/carpeta} \;

pero me lanza un nuevo error

find: paths must precede expression:
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: fíjate donde pones las llaves -exec {mv -f /media/carpeta} \;, tienes que poner -exec mv -f {} /media/carpeta \;